# add to Interface IAugmentedJQuery from local file

Tags: angularjs, typescript

First try at TypeScript. All excited!

Im extending `angular.element` (IAugmentedJQuery) with some custom methods via `angular.element.prototype.myMethod=fn() {...};` The function works, however TypeScript won't allow it. The compiler says:

> error TS2339: Property 'myMethod' does not exist on type 'IAugmentedJQuery'.

I tried the obvious:

```
interface IAugmentedJQuery{
    myMethod(): IAugmentedJQuery;
}
```

But that doesn't help. However, if I add the definition in the angular.d.ts file where it is first defined, everything works. Shouldn't that do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add to an interface, the additional interface must be in the same common root.

Because `IAugmentedJQuery` is in the `angular` module, you would need to add your definition to that root too.

```
declare module angular {
    interface IAugmentedJQuery{
        myMethod(): IAugmentedJQuery;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes total sense!

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "same common root" you are referring to the module name(s), correct?